# Syntax error, unexpected $end In for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, syntax-error

first thread i post here. I have been searching here for answers and almost always got them. But this one is a slightly different.
I have this php code snippet

```
<tr>
  <td>
<?php if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) { //if there are records found
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {  //do while there are rows
  if($English==1)
    $Title=$row["sSubCatEng"];
  else
    $Title=$row["sSubCat"];
  echo $Title;
  }
} ?> 
</td>
</tr>
<?php
  $NumOfItems= 9; //Number of items per page.
  $ItemsCount=count($ItemPartID); //number of items in ItemPartID array
  $Page = $_GET["Page"]; //puts the var in a local one
  if(($NumOfItems*$Page) > $ItemsCount) // if it is the last page
  {
    $StopFor = $ItemsCount % $NumOfItems; //stop when you modulo
    $j = ($NumOfItems*($Page - 1));
    $indexFor = $StopFor;
  }
  else
  {
    $StopFor = $NumOfItems * $Page;
    $j =($NumOfItems*($Page - 1));
    $indexFor = $StopFor - $j;
  }
  ?>
<tr>
<?php if($English==0){ ?>
 <td dir="rtl" align="center" colspan="3">
 <?php echo $ItemsCount; ?> <?php echo $Title; ?> <?php echo $NumOfItems; ?>
 <?php }else { ?>
 <td align="center" colspan="3">
 Currently there are <?php echo $ItemsCount." ".$Title; ?> in the catalog.Only <?php echo $NumOfItems; ?> are displayed on each page.
 <? } ?>

<? for($i=0;$i<$var;$i++) {
    echo "<td style='width:30px;height:30px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-      width:1px;background-color: lightgray;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;";
    if($Page==($i+1))
        echo "color:red;";
    echo "' onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor = 'pointer';\"      onmousemove=\"this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';this.style.color='white';\"     onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='lightgray';";
    if($Page==($i+1))
        echo "this.style.color='red';";
    else
        echo "this.style.color='black';";
    echo "\" onClick='window.location=\"Catalog.php?Cat={$Category}&Page=".($i+1)."&SubCat=    {$SubCat}&lang={$Lang}\"' >".($i+1); 
    echo "</td>";
}
?>
```

It's a little messy ,i just don't know how to add code snippets.
I have done some debugging and got that the 1st line (the line of the for) is the prob, yet I can't find the problem.
(i replaced $var with 1 and it still didn't help).
Thank you.

Comment: `unexpected $end` usually means you forgot a closing `}` for the for loop, however, this code is a bit messy, but ultimately fine. Is this the _exact_ code you have there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten curly braces {} for the if/else statements.

**EDIT:** Try changing:
`<? } ?>` to `<? }`just before `for($i=0;$i<$var;$i++) {`

(You missed the php `<?` starting tag for the for loop.)

Comment: They are one lined so they don't require {}

Comment: Ok, that wasn't obvious before your reformat of the code :) You obviously have more code above that snippet, and I'm guessing you have some syntax error above that causing you to look at the wrong place for error. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @user1467394: stricly, you don't _need_ them, but you fooled 2 people here into thinking it... Imagine those are colleagues. Imagine those are colleagues working frantically to fix a problem occuring at that moment. It isn't part of your current problem, but please: clearity before brevity: your code should also be clear to others, or be prepared for some angry coworkers.

Comment: I'm truly sorry, this is my first thread and my code is long. I have already a <? and i edited the code. Is there a way to PM you the file?

Comment: No not really as I don't see this as a smaller question anymore but more of a code review. Check your code for mismatching number of { vs } and vice versa. Also make sure you have short tags enabled for php, or change every `<?` to `<?php`.

Comment: Wow, i can't believe it was the short tag.. i have searched for them and found none. Thank you very much both Wrikken and Jite